# Pexpect won't pass commands to Panduit PDU (Smartzone G5) via SSH

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, pexpect

###### Problem

I've got a program using "Pexpect" to send commands over SSH. Its purpose is to SSH into a Panduit PDU (smartzone G5) and turn off port 1.

I can SSH into the PDU and run `dev outlet 1 1 off` and get the port to turn off, but it doesn't work when I try to run the same command from my program. It puzzles me as this method is no different than me logging in via SSH using iterm and typing. Is this a me problem or just how the PDU behaves?

###### What I've Tried

I've tested `pexpect` thoroughly on a Linux server using `mkdir` and `touch` to create directories and files so I know it works without issue there, but when I use it on the Panduit PDU the PDU ignores the commands.

I use `time.sleep()` to allow the PDU to catch up as it is a slow system and seems to have a queue for multiple commands.

It's not a module issue or interpreter issue or anything silly like that; the program itself is fine. (Though I'm sure it's not up to standards or safe but who cares if I can't get the program to work in the first place seriously.)

###### Why Pexpect?

I must use Pexpect as Paramiko and Fabric don't work for this particular connection.

I must specify `ssh -F /dev/null admin@ipaddress` otherwise the PDU rejects the SSH session and I cannot get pxssh or fabric or paramiko to do this so that's why I don't use them.

I'm aware of stuff like `.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())` for Paramiko and `s = pxssh.pxssh(options={"StrictHostKeyChecking": "no", "UserKnownHostsFile": "/dev/null"})` and they do not work. Hence Pexpect.

###### Code

```py
import os                      
import pexpect
import time     
import sys

server_ip = "192.168.0.1"
server_user = "admin"
server_pass = "password"

child = pexpect.spawn('bash')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
child.expect('')

# This is the only way to access the PDU, Paramiko wont work either.
child.sendline('ssh -F /dev/null %s@%s -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no' % (server_user, server_ip))
child.expect("admin@192.168.0.1's password:")
child.sendline(server_pass)
child.expect('PANDUIT>')


time.sleep(3) # Wait for PDU to catch up or it wont recognise the command
child.sendline('dev outlet 1 1 off') # Power off port 1
print('\nfinished') # \n is there otherwise it gets sucked into the stdout
```

For reference this is what happens when I use Iterm to manually connect and enter commands, it works perfectly.
I've tried to use `child.expect('SUCCESS')` but it can't be seen. The only thing pexpect seems to be able to find inside the PDU is `child.expect('\n')` which I think may be from a buffer or something.

```py
~/Documents ❯ ssh -F /dev/null admin@192.168.0.1   
admin@192.168.0.1's password:
 Type ? for command listing
sys     PDU system configure and setting
net     PDU net application configure and setting
usr     PDU user operation
dev     PDU device setting
pwr     PDU power setting


PANDUIT>dev outlet 1 1 off
SUCCESS
```

And this is what my code outputs:

```py
~/Documents❯ python3 code.py 
ssh -F /dev/null admin@192.168.0.1 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ ssh -F /dev/null admin@192.168.0.1 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no
admin@192.168.0.1's password:



 Type ? for command listing
sys     PDU system configure and setting
net     PDU net application configure and setting
usr         PDU user operation
dev     PDU device setting
pwr     PDU power setting

PANDUIT>
finished
```